# FragmentManager with muliple fragment and setting ActionBar on fragment does not work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I have an app with one activity and 4 main fragment, I added this 4 main fragment to the FragmentManager on onCreate of Activity and hide all for startup of app, when a tab is selected by user I hide the previous fragment and show the selected one, I do this for using the backstack of ChildFragmentManager of this 4 fragments, Because I want separate backstack for each of this fragments. After rotation I want to call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled for adding this button to current fragment if this fragment has nested fragment, but there isn't any way to find what fragment is in showing state and if I call this method in onCreate of fragment it called 4 times, and just the last fragment set the button(Not the current fragment)!

Comment: Can you show some code?  Or what is your question?

Comment: I have a FragmentManager with multi-fragment added to it in main activity, that one of this fragment is visible, when mobile rotate all fragment is recreate, how can I determine what fragment is visible?